# Optimizing solutions with linear restrictions

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Let's say I have a linear system with *`N`* variables, but I only have *`N-1`* equations (constraints). How can I get the feasable set (range) for each of the N variables using R?

**Example:**

```
A <- matrix(data=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
                   0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
                   0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
                   0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
                   0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,
                   1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
                   ),
            ncol=8, byrow=T)
b <- matrix(data=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.06,0.18,0.12,1),
            ncol=1)
> A
##     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
##[1,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
##[2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1
##[3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
##[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
##[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1
##[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
##[7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
> b
##     [,1]
##[1,] 0.20
##[2,] 0.40
##[3,] 0.60
##[4,] 0.06
##[5,] 0.18
##[6,] 0.12
##[7,] 1.00
```

Additional constraint: every value must be possitive and should be between 0 and 1 (this last one can be ommited, since the last equation adds up to 1 with only possitive values)

Comment: These type of problems could be solved using statistical tools as Regularized Regression. One of them is the famous LASSO.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are describing is probably best approached by linear programming, since you have a set of linear constraints (Ax = b, x >= 0, x <= 1) and a linear objective (either maximize or minimize some x_i). Given the simple structure of your program, I would solve it using the `lpSolve` package in R:

```
library(lpSolve)
for (idx in seq_len(ncol(A))) {
  for (type in c("min", "max")) {
    mod <- lp(direction = type,
              objective.in = as.numeric(seq_len(ncol(A)) == idx),
              const.mat = rbind(A, diag(ncol(A))),
              const.dir = c(rep("=", length(b)), rep("<=", ncol(A))),
              const.rhs = c(b, rep(1, ncol(A))))
    print(paste("Variable:", idx, "type:", type, "value", mod$objval))
  }
}
# [1] "Variable: 1 type: min value 0.1"
# [1] "Variable: 1 type: max value 0.12"
# [1] "Variable: 2 type: min value 0"
# [1] "Variable: 2 type: max value 0.02"
# [1] "Variable: 3 type: min value 0.26"
# [1] "Variable: 3 type: max value 0.28"
# [1] "Variable: 4 type: min value 0"
# [1] "Variable: 4 type: max value 0.02"
# [1] "Variable: 5 type: min value 0.34"
# [1] "Variable: 5 type: max value 0.36"
# [1] "Variable: 6 type: min value 0.12"
# [1] "Variable: 6 type: max value 0.14"
# [1] "Variable: 7 type: min value 0.06"
# [1] "Variable: 7 type: max value 0.08"
# [1] "Variable: 8 type: min value 0.04"
# [1] "Variable: 8 type: max value 0.06"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using methods as the Regularized Regression. There are packages in `R` such as `lars` or `glmnet`. I would advise on reading this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58531/using-lasso-from-lars-or-glmnet-package-in-r-for-variable-selection).

Basically, in `R` you would run

```
library(lars)
model=lars(A,b)
coef(model)
      [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]   [,5]   [,6]    [,7] [,8]
[1,] 0.000 0.00 0.000    0 0.0000 0.0000 0.00000    0
[2,] 0.000 0.00 0.000    0 0.0982 0.0000 0.00000    0
[3,] 0.131 0.00 0.000    0 0.2000 0.0000 0.00000    0
[4,] 0.138 0.00 0.185    0 0.3849 0.0000 0.00000    0
[5,] 0.109 0.00 0.260    0 0.4000 0.0600 0.00000    0
[6,] 0.109 0.00 0.260    0 0.3997 0.0603 0.00029    0
[7,] 0.100 0.02 0.280    0 0.3600 0.1200 0.06000    0
```

The results is a 7x8 matrix, where at each row from top to bottom the most important variable is entered in the model. For example, the first row tries to fit the model with an intercept only. The second introduces the strongest variable of the 8 which is the 5-th, and so on. From the results you can see that the variables 4 and 8 have zero coefficient all along, signifying that they are not important given all the others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the 'nullspace' of A, e.g. with package *MASS* or function nullspace() in *pracma*. First compute a least-squares solution, and then add a linear combination of the vectors in the nullspace:

```
library(pracma)
N <- nullspace(A)
# 0.3535534 * c(-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1)
x0 <- qr.solve(A, b)
# [1]  0.16 -0.04  0.22  0.06  0.30  0.18  0.12  0.00
```

and  x0 + x*N, x real, generates all possible solutions.

N in this example is 1-dim., because the rank of A is 1. With even less equations, the nullspace will have more dimensions.

Comment: Is there a way to add the restriction that all solutions must be possitive?

Comment: There is no x such that all components of  x0 + x*N are positive as you can verify by deriving inequalities for x from all components (if I calculated it corrrectly).